# Magnetic field modeling with noises

Tags: magnetic-fields, simulations, stochastic-processes, noise

I am trying to make a 3d grid of a magnetic field with some noises (which will be added to the ordinary field) for a computer simulation. I have the formula for the ordinary field, also I am using a fast Fourier transform (FFT) to create Gaussian Random Field for noises.

The problem is, that the noise field I have created is a scalar field not a vector. So I need to find a way for creating vector-valued Gaussian random field whose divergence will be equal to zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the fact that the divergence-free constraint, $\nabla\cdot\mathbf{B}=0$, becomes
$$
\mathbf{k}\cdot\tilde{\mathbf{B}} = 0
$$
in Fourier space, where $\tilde{\mathbf{B}}$ denotes the Fourier transform of $\mathbf{B}$ and $\mathbf{k}$ is the wavevector.

To get a vector-valued field, you could first generate a random field for each of the three components (e.g. $\tilde{\mathbf{B}} =(\tilde{B}_x,\tilde{B}_y,\tilde{B}_z)$ in Fourier space). Once you have these, you can subtract off the projection of $\tilde{\mathbf{B}}$ along $\mathbf{k}$ to satisfy $\mathbf{k}\cdot\tilde{\mathbf{B}} = 0$:
$$
\tilde{\mathbf{B}} \to \tilde{\mathbf{B}} - \frac{\mathbf{k}}{k^2}(\tilde{\mathbf{B}}\cdot\mathbf{k}).
$$

Taking the inverse Fourier transform of this new $\tilde{\mathbf{B}}$ will then give you a divergence-free noise field.

Comment: Thanks for your respond. I was thinking about decomposing my field using Helmholtz decomposition and take the divergence-free part. And eventually I've derived the very same formula that you've suggested)